Understanding Pulse Doppler Radar pulse compression
I am reading about pulse doppler radar book where it states that to increase the SNR we use wider pulse width and to increase the range resolution we use pulse compression i.e., match filtering. After reading through the text it states that the after pulse compression the pulse width is approximately equal to \$\frac{1}{B}\$, where B is the bandwidth of the transmitted signal (LFM signal). To prove this I started by considering a transmitted LFM signal
$$s(t) = A\exp{(j\pi kt^2)}\text{ for } t \in \left(\frac{-T}{2},\frac{T}{2}\right)$$
where k is chirp rate and $$k = \frac{B}{T}$$
Here:

B is bandwidth of transmitted signal
T is pulse width of transmitted signal
A is amplitude of transmitted signal
Now, the match filter is nothing but the time-reversed complex conjugate of the transmitted signal:
$$h(t) = s^*(-t) = A\exp{(-j\pi kt^2)} \text{ for } t \in \left(\frac{-T}{2},\frac{T}{2}\right)$$
Output of match filter:
$$y(t) = s(t)*h(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}s(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}A^2\exp{\left(j\pi\frac{B}{T}\tau^2\right)}\exp{\left(-j\pi\frac{B}{T}(t-\tau)^2\right)}d\tau$$
Which further simplifies to,
$$y(t) = A^2T\exp{\left(-j\pi\frac{B}{T}t^2\right)}\delta\left(\frac{B}{T}t\right) = \frac{A^2T^2}{B}\exp{\left(-j\pi\frac{B}{T}t^2\right)}\delta\left(t\right)$$
This implies that we get a sharp peak at t = 0 and pulse width is 0 for ideal case. I don't understand where the book is getting it result of

$$ \text{pulse width } \approx \frac{1}{B}$$

Well, first of all notice that when $\displaystyle\Re\left(\text{n}+\text{m}\right)\le0$:
$$\text{y}\left(t\right):=\int\limits_\mathbb{R}\exp\left(\text{n}x^2+\text{m}\left(t-x\right)^2\right)\space\text{d}x=\sqrt{-\frac{\displaystyle\pi}{\displaystyle\text{n}+\text{m}}}\cdot\exp\left(\frac{\displaystyle\text{n}\text{m}t^2}{\displaystyle\text{n}+\text{m}}\right)\tag1$$

What book are you using?

@Envidia Lu, J. (2019) Design Technology of Synthetic Aperture Radar. West Sussex, England: John Wiley & Sons Limited.

The nominal matched-filter output of an LFM pulse of length \$\tau\$ sweeping bandwidth \$\beta\$ is:
$$y(t) = \big|\frac{\sin[\pi\beta t(1 - |t|/\tau)]}{\pi\beta t}\big|, \ -\tau \leq t \leq\tau \ [1]$$
The Rayleigh resolution, which is the resolution commonly in used in radar, is found by finding the roots of \$y(t)\$ and assuming \$\beta\tau \gg1\$ gives us
$$t' \approx \frac{1}{\beta}$$
This is the resolution in time of the matched filter output (cross-correlation), which is what pulse compression is based on. Don't conflate this with the term "pulse width" since that is usually reserved for the width of the pulse actually transmitted. There isn't some new pulse that was created that is somehow shorter, it's simply the output of the matched filter, where the more bandwidth you put into the pulse, the narrower the response is shaped, and thus you can achieve a finer resolution.
The term "pulse compression" is more of a descriptor of what you're trying to achieve, which is to use a larger pulse width (more energy) that achieves the resolution of a shorter one.
[1] Richards, Mark A. (2014). Fundamentals of Radar Signal Processing.

In the book "Design Technology of Synthetic Aperture Radar" by J. Lu (2019), it is stated that "The bandwidth of the signal is then given by $B = k\tau_p$. After matched filtering, the pulse width $\tau_p$ is compressed into $1/B$, resulting in improved resolution."

@SiddharthSingh The pulse width $\tau_p$ is an equivalent pulse width. It is of course used in various equations (like the radar range equation) and is useful to handle it in this manner, but just know there is not a real pulse anywhere of that width. It is simply the result of the output of a matched filter.
